# Regular Expressions C++ Qt

Tags: c++, regex, qt

```
QRegExp rx("\\btest\\b");
rx.indexIn("this is a test string");
QString captured = rx.cap(1);
std::string capturedstr = captured.toUtf8().constData();
std::cout << capturedstr;
```

I wanted the above to print out test and match the word test within the string but it doesn't seem to be doing that. Could anyone shed some light here? Using QT.

Comment: When working with regular expressions in Qt, the RegExp example program (located in $YOUR_QT_DIR\examples\tools\regexp\release) is incredibly helpful. It allows you to enter regular expressions and test the results without recompiling. Documentation [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/tools-regexp.html)

Comment: Thanks @docsteer, the example is really helpful when designing our regexp. In Qt5.2.1, it's located here: $QT_DIR/examples/widgets/tools/regexp/release

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have any capturing parens in your regex so there is no capture group 1. Try this instead:

```
QRegExp rx("\\b(test)\\b");
```

Comment: ...or use `rx.cap(0)` to access the entire match.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `rx.cap(1)` with `rx.cap(0)`
The entire match has index 0.